# failed to Install HAXM while installing android studio

Tags: android-studio

Failed to install intel HAXM. 
This computer meets the requirments for HAXM, but intel virtualization technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled.

This message appears in between installation process, though after installation studio is running. Please let me know effects of HAXM installation failure on studio. How to correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAXM will speed up your emulator (in my experience dramatically).

VT-x is enabled via your machines bios (look for references to virtualisation and ensure they are enabled).

There's little downside to enabling virtualisation in your bios to get the benefits of HAXM but if you don't want to bother it won't stop you using Android Studio.